# Can CStringList increase memory and never freed until closed the application

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have an application which runs slower during the time (remarkable after days).
I still have no clue, where this is coming, but I see in Taskmanager, the app is constantly consume more memory (working set and commmit size).

I have special Traces to visualize Traces to differents OutputPanes.
I do this by simply add Traces to one and more different `CStringList`.
Like this code example

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  TRACE HW_MESSAGES
void TRACE_HW(LPCTSTR pszstring)
{
  CHwTestApp* pApp = &theApp;
  if (pApp)
    return;

  TRACE(pszstring);     

  if (theApp.mStrHwList.GetCount() > kMAXTRACEs)    
  {
    CString ob = theApp.mStrHwList.RemoveHead();
  }
  theApp.mStrHwList.AddTail(pszstring);
  
}
```

My question can `CStringList` become more ane more greater by calling `RemoveHead` and  `AddTail`?
Does he compact at once internally his used physically memory or delayed?

Comment: Who's cleaning up the `pszstring`? `AddTail` is making a copy, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code posted will not leak memory. The specific `CStringList` overload for `RemoveHead()` passes ownership out of the container, and the local `ob` object gets immediately destroyed.

`AddTail()` makes a `CString` copy of the passed in character string pointer, and passes that copy into the `CStringList`. You can thus run the following code indefinitely, without the memory increasing:

```cpp
while (true) {
    CString str = _T("Test trace entry");
    TRACE_HW(str.GetString());
}
```

The crucial point here is that `TRACE_HW` will not assume ownership of the memory pointed to by `pszstring`. So long as the caller makes sure to clean that up, everything is fine (this is what the local `CString` object does).

If, however, you change that to the following:

```cpp
while (true) {
    TCHAR* str = new TCHAR[256];
    TRACE_HW(str);
}
```

things are starting to change. This is allocating memory, passes a pointer into `TRACE_HW` which merely observes the memory, but then no-one is ever cleaning that up.

All things being equal, the issue is with the caller of `TRACE_HW`, not `TRACE_HW` itself.

---

Well, sort of, anyway. The function signature of `TRACE_HW` certainly invites clients into *assuming* that they're passing off ownership. Pointer arguments in C++ generally model transfer of ownership. If you want to express the property of being an observer only, a `const` reference is more appropriate.

If `TRACE_HW` had the following signature instead:

```cpp
void TRACE_HW(CString const& msg)
```

it would be far more obvious to clients that they retain responsibility for the object passed off to the interface for inspection only. When the call expires, they're still responsible for dealing with the actual object.

Comment: Ok, then we can exclude memory leak here. Good point about the properly signature, I am motivated to change it, but I have similiar signatures with `...` as parameter ex. `void TRACE_CT(LPCTSTR pszstring, ...)`. Can I chang it to the new signature with `(CString  const& msg, ...)` as parameter too? Never seen.

Comment: @tom You *could* do that, but then (I think) you can no longer call the function with a string literal. What I would do instead is limit `TRACE_HW` to *only* accept string literals. That'd require making it a function template, something like `template <size_t N> TRACE_HW(TCHAR const (&msg)[N], ...)`. That would make `TRACE_HW(_T("test"));` legal, but disallow passing raw pointers such as `TRACE_HW(new TCHAR[42]);`. That'll fail your build and point to locations that potentially pass "unowned" pointers along for the ride (causing the leak).

Comment: Sorry, typo, that should read `template <size_t N> void TRACE_HW(TCHAR const (&msg)[N], ...)`.

Comment: It's very likely that it's the buffer you're [`vsnprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsnprintf-vsnprintf-vsnprintf-l-vsnwprintf-vsnwprintf-l)-ing into. That buffer needs an owner who's cleaning up once it is no longer needed. You could use [`CString::FormatV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#formatv) instead, which formats a message into a buffer that's owned by the `CString` object.

Comment: It seems now solved. I have replaced `_vsntprintf_s` with your proposal `CString::FormatV' .

Answer (score 1):

`CString ob = ...` is destroyed immediately at the scope. Therefore, it isn't the leak cause.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/cgenericlist-removehead

According to this however, `RemoveHead` returns an OBJECT*. Where does that go? It's duplicated by CString all right, but the original OBJECT* is left unowed?

Comment: The `CStringList` class is derived from `CObject`, not `CGenericList` or `CObList`; these classes have member functions named similarly, completely different though. `CStringList::RemoveHead()` returns a `CString` object, which is copy-constructed (from the node being removed) during the call (will be deleted when it goes out of scope). The node removed is also released, so no need to release anything. Not adequately described in the documentation, had to check the code for this...